# create Custom waiter in boto3 for efs to wait until mount target is deleted

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-efs

1. I have to delete file systems that do not have tag Retain=true.
2. For the File systems that have this tag set to false, the targets that
   are mounted need to be deleted.
3. Since deletion of mounting resources
   is taking time, I need to wait until I can delete my EFS. So I
   designed this Custom wait until the mounting targets are removed.

The output of the following code is

> Waiter does not exist: TargetDeleted

Here is my Code

Thanks in advance

```
import boto3
from botocore.waiter import WaiterModel
from botocore.waiter import create_waiter_with_client

client = boto3.client('efs')

waiter_name = "TargetDeleted"
waiter_config = {
    "version": 2,
    "waiters": {
            "MountTargetDeleted": {
                  "delay": 30,
                  "operation": "DescribeMountTargets",
                  "maxAttempts": 90,
                  "acceptors": [
                    {
                      "expected": "deleted",
                      "matcher": "pathAll",
                      "state": "success",
                      "argument": "MountTargets[].LifeCycleState"
                    },
                    {
                      "expected": "updating",
                      "matcher": "pathAll",
                      "state": "failure",
                      "argument": "MountTargets[].LifeCycleState"
                    },
                    {
                      "expected": "creating",
                      "matcher": "pathAll",
                      "state": "failure",
                      "argument": "MountTargets[].LifeCycleState"
                    }
                  ]
            }
        }

}

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    response = client.describe_file_systems()
    fs=response['FileSystems']

    
    for details in fs:
        
        fid=details['FileSystemId']
        tag_response= client.describe_tags(
            FileSystemId=fid
        )
        alltags=tag_response['Tags']
        
        if {'Key': 'Retain', 'Value': 'True'} not in alltags:
            try:
                client.delete_file_system(FileSystemId=fid)
                print("The file", details['FileSystemId'],"deleted")
            except:
                print(client.describe_file_systems(FileSystemId=fid))
                response1 = client.describe_mount_targets(
                    FileSystemId=fid
                )
                
                fs1=response1['MountTargets']
                
                for detail in fs1:
                    mid=detail['MountTargetId']
                    response3 = client.delete_mount_target(
                    MountTargetId=mid
                    )
                
                try:
                    waiter_model = WaiterModel(waiter_config)
                    backup_waiter = create_waiter_with_client(waiter_name, waiter_model, client)
                    client.delete_file_system(FileSystemId=fid)
                    print("The file", details['FileSystemId'],"deleted")
                
                except Exception as e: 
                    print(e)
                    
        else:
            print("Retain tag set to True. The file", details['FileSystemId'],"cannot be deleted")
```

Comment: why don't you do except Exception as e: print(e)  instead of print(not working) so you an see the exception being thrown and you can learn more about what is wrong.

Comment: @lynkfox output is Waiter does not exist: TargetDeleted

Comment: @lynkfox I have edited the code

Answer (score 1):

The waiter name in the config should match the name of the waiter.

```
waiter_name = "MountTargetDeleted"
waiter_config = {
    "version": 2,
    "waiters": {
            "MountTargetDeleted": {
                  "delay": 30,
                  "operation": "DescribeMountTargets",
                  "maxAttempts": 90,
                  "acceptors": [
                    {
                      "expected": "deleted",
                      "matcher": "pathAll",
                      "state": "success",
                      "argument": "MountTargets[].LifeCycleState"
                    },
                    {
                      "expected": "updating",
                      "matcher": "pathAll",
                      "state": "failure",
                      "argument": "MountTargets[].LifeCycleState"
                    },
                    {
                      "expected": "creating",
                      "matcher": "pathAll",
                      "state": "failure",
                      "argument": "MountTargets[].LifeCycleState"
                    }
                  ]
            }
        }

}
```

Also, you might consider pathAny for the failure condition.